# Mysql: Order results accrording to the number of matches in a WHERE clause?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-order-by, where-clause

Is it possible to order (DESC) the results of a **MYSQL query** depending on the **number of matches** it has in the **WHERE clause,** that has been separated by **multiple OR operators**?

I would like to do this to the following query:

```
SELECT column_1, column_2, column_2
FROM tbl_table 
WHERE column_1 LIKE '%$string1%' 
OR column_2 LIKE '%$string2%' 
OR column_3 LIKE '%$string3%'
ORDER BY ... "
```

Comment: You should use the full text search. This will give a score to your search. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html

Comment: You can also do a neat trick comparing the size of the haystack before and after the needles are removed.

Answer (score 3):

You can use SUM() and GROUP BY as so:

```
SELECT column_1, column_2, column_3, 
    SUM(IF(column_1 LIKE '%$string1%', 1, 0)) as S1,
    SUM(IF(column_2 LIKE '%$string2%', 1, 0)) as S2,
    SUM(IF(column_3 LIKE '%$string3%', 1, 0)) as S3
FROM tbl_table
WHERE column_1 LIKE '%$string1%'
    OR column_2 LIKE '%$string2%'
    OR column_3 LIKE '%$string3%'
GROUP BY column_1, column_2, column_3
ORDER BY S1 DESC, S2 DESC, S3 DESC
```

Comment: I'm not sure I see how SUM would make sense here. If column1 matches, you will just get the number of times (column_1, column_2, column_3) appears in the table for S1; similarly for S2 and S3. You'll get COUNT(*) or 0 for S1, S2, S3.

Comment: If column_1 matches, the IF evaluates to 1, if it doesn't match, a 0. Grouping then uses the SUM of these, which will tell how many column_1 matches there are total.

Comment: But your grouping is going to mean you get 0 or the number of rows with the same values for column_1, column_2, AND column_3; not how many rows match column_1.

Answer (score 2):

This is this only way I am aware of:

```
SELECT column_1, column_2, column_2
, IF(column_1 LIKE '%$string1%', 1, 0)
  + IF(column_2 LIKE '%$string2%', 1, 0) 
  + IF(column_3 LIKE '%$string3%', 1, 0)
  AS matchCount
FROM tbl_table 
WHERE column_1 LIKE '%$string1%' 
  OR column_2 LIKE '%$string2%' 
  OR column_3 LIKE '%$string3%'
ORDER BY matchCount DESC
```